# Spring WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter permitAll() does not allow REST POST requests from c# client?

Tags: c#, spring-boot

I have this setup in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to allow my client application to send POST request to the "/commands/" path on server:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/commands/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/files/**").authenticated()
            .and().
            formLogin();
    }
```

GET requests are fine,however the csrf seems be required for POST requests after this setup. I get following result if I don't login:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1497904660159,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.",
    "path": "/commands/add"
}
```

If I login and attach the cookies from login request with C# client code, I will get following error:

```
{
    "timestamp":1497897646380,
    "status":403,
    "error":"Forbidden",
    "message":"Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.",
    "path":"/commands/add"
}
```

My C# code client for post looks like this:

```
public String SendJsonCommandByPost(String url, string data)
{
    try
    {
        WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Proxy = null;
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Timeout = TIMEOUT;
        ((HttpWebRequest)req).CookieContainer = myCookieContainer;
        PrintCookies(myCookieContainer);
        req.Headers.Add("X-CSRF-TOKEN", _csrftoken);
        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        ((HttpWebRequest)req).UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
        byte[] postdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        req.ContentLength = postdata.Length;
        Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(postdata, 0, postdata.Length);
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();
        string source;

        Console.WriteLine(req.Headers);
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
            {
                source = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            req.GetResponse().Close();
            return source;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exp);
        if (exp is WebException)
        {
            var webexp = (WebException)exp;
            Console.WriteLine(webexp.Response.Headers);
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(webexp.Response.GetResponseStream());
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

May I know what could cause this kind of issue? Thank you!

Comment: I believe you are using spring version > 4.0. Which has csrf enabled by default. You will need to disable it.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-configure

Comment: Just a word of caution, rather than disabling csrf, it will be better if you add the csrf token to the request

Comment: Thank you @Shibashis, I can now get it to work by adding http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/commands/**"); It is working, but yes I want to get the code to work with csrf token. I already added the "X-CSRF-TOKEN" token from login forum into C# post command. And the reply is still: "Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found."

Comment: Are you testing a local instance of the springboot service?

Comment: Yes, I am testing it locally.

Comment: In your c# logic, does my cookie container has the jsessioid details for the service to identify correctly? The csrf token is tracked on the service side and hence needs a request in the same session.

Comment: Do you have a `SimpleCorsFilter`? Can you show it?

Comment: Hi, @Shibashis, sorry I haven't reply. Yes, As long as I can track, the JSessionID is the one returned from the login reply. I will try to host the service remotely so that I can intercept the whole html package.

Comment: @lazarov As far as I know, I don't have the SimpleCorsFilter. My testing code is based on sample code from spring boot examples. It should be very simple. But thank you!

Comment: Can you verify the jsession id is being sent to the server? "Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found" indicates that the request is not being made in the same session as the login request.

Comment: @Shibashis I tested the code. It seems like the JSESSIONID is [value1] before login. And it got changed to another by server in Login process to [value2]. Then every request after login uses [value2]. That is what I found using Chrome debug console. And my C# code should work the same way. But I can not be really sure because I can not get C# application's complete header locally. I will test it with a analyzer proxy or something, But thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

add this line.

http.csrf().disable();

By default csrf is enabled so your post requests are getting blocked. Try this. It works for me

Comment: This was already given in the comment section: do not remove CSRF tokens, there's a reason for them to be included in recent projects